# Showing that $x^2+y^2-1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$ [Direct approach].

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I want to check if my reasoning is correct and makes sense. I know other approaches, but I wonder if this one works also:

1. To show that $x^2+y^2-1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$, it's enough to check that $x^2+(y^2-1)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[y][x]$ as there is a ring isomorphism between $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$ and $\mathbb{Q}[y][x]$.
2. As $x^2+y^2-1$ is a quadratic polynomial, then it's enough to show that $\pm\sqrt{y^2-1}$ does not belong to $\mathbb{Q}[y]$.
3. If $\sqrt{y^2-1}$ belongs to $\mathbb{Q}[y]$, then there exists $f(y)\in \mathbb{Q}[y]$ s.t.
   $$\sqrt{y^2-1}=f(y)\text{ i.e. }y^2-1=f^2(y)\text{ }[*].$$
4. But, then $(y-f(y))(y+f(y))=1$. So, $y-f(y)=c$ for some $c\in\mathbb{Q}$ with $c\neq0$ i.e. $f(y)=y-c$.
5. From $[*]$, follows that $y^2-1=(y-c)^2$ i.e. $y=\frac{c^2-1}{2c}\in\mathbb{Q}$ which is a contradiction.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you know the Eisenstein criterion?  Viewing the polynomial in $\mathbf Q[y][x]$ as a quadratic polynomial in $x$ it is Eisenstein at $y+1$ (or $y-1$), so it is irreducible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually need to show that $1 - y^2$ is not a square in $\mathbb{Q}[y]$ (you need to pay attention to the sign here because you're not working over $\mathbb{C}$), which is even easier since its quadratic coefficient is negative. Of course it is still not a square over $\mathbb{C}$ and there are many ways to see this, e.g.

- it has two distinct roots, or
- by comparing degrees we see that a square root must be linear, and by comparing the quadratic and constant terms it must have the form $\pm iy \pm 1$, whose square has the wrong linear term.

Comment: Sorry, but from where $\pm iy\pm 1$ came up?

Comment: @eightc: if $1 - y^2 = f(y)^2$ then comparing degrees we have $f(y) = ay + b$. Squaring this gives $f(y)^2 = a^2 y^2 + 2aby + b^2$ and comparing coefficients gives $a^2 = -1, b^2 = 1$ so $a = \pm i, b = \pm 1$ which means $2ab \neq 0$ so the linear term can't match. There is no such $f$ so there are many ways to arrive at a contradiction, this is just another example.